# App has Wear functionality that is visible to the user

Tags: android, wear-os

Recently I sent an app to Play Store which supports wearables.
I received this as feedback:

App has Wear functionality that is visible to the user.

What does that mean?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/wear.html

Comment: @2Dee I've already gone to the docs many times to see all the guide lines. And the feedback is simple and short, not explaining what is the matter.

Comment: They're saying they didn't see any Wear functionality when reviewing your application. What kind of Wear integration did you do?

Comment: Got the same for a watch face. Doesn't get more wearable.

Comment: @MarceloNoguti: My app also rejected for this reason.It is working fine on my side.What you did after they rejected ? Please update me ASAP..

Comment: @Debugger I just ensured I had at least one screenshot at Play Store showing the wearable running my app. This solved my problem.

Comment: @MarceloNoguti : May i know how you packaged Android Wear when you submit to playstore ?I have given two methods.Which method you used ?
1)Did you signed your android wear apk and included the apk path to your handheld and sign the handheld apk and submit.
dependencies {
  ...
  wearApp files('/path/to/wearable_app.apk')
}
2)Declared a Gradle dependency in the handheld app's build.gradle file that points to the wearable app module.Then you signed the apk and published to playstore.
dependencies {
   wearApp project(':wearable')
}
which method you used ?

Comment: @Debugger We used the second method you mentioned. We put a dependency in handheld app's build.gradle. Also, we double checked in wearable build.gradle the applicationId, versionCode and versionName so they were exactly the same as in handheld AndroidManifest. Some other issue we had was about flavors: we made sure the same configuration for flavors in handheld build.gradle was present in wearable  build.gradle. There were many tries until a last one to be accepted

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you uploaded the `wear` module APK instead of the `mobile` APK (which embeds the first one).
Remember that your app needs to go on the phone first, then the watch. Hence the dual packaging.

Comment: Not really, I uploaded the mobile APK. Before uploading I also tested it installing on my phone and then it was installed automatically on my wear. Tried sending again to Play Store and it was accepted. It was missing some screenshots =/

Comment: Interesting. The website should not let you publish at all if screenshots are missing. Anyway, glad you made it.

Comment: @MonoThreaded:My app also rejected for this reason.It is working fine on my side.I have uploaded the mobile apk only.What you did after they rejected ? Please update me ASAP..

Comment: What reason are you talking about?

Comment: @MonoThreaded:
May i know how you packaged Android Wear when you submit to playstore ?I have given two methods.Which method you used ? 1)Did you signed your android wear apk and included the apk path to your handheld and sign the handheld apk and submit. dependencies { ... wearApp files('/path/to/wearable_app.apk') } 2)Declared a Gradle dependency in the handheld app's build.gradle file that points to the wearable app module.Then you signed the apk and published to playstore. dependencies { wearApp project(':wearable') } which method you used ?

Comment: I started off a sample app in Android Studio. It provides all the wiring you need. Then just click Build/Generate Signed APK and upload the output to Google Play. It wraps Mobile and Wear apps.